# Hive Join where != not working

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

In hive, I'm working with two tables, each have same fields.  The idea is I only want rows from table "one" which are not located in table "two".  At this time, I'm not getting any returned result.

table one

```
id  | category
i_1 | c_123
i_1 | c_234
i_1 | c_345
i_1 | c_456
i_2 | c_456
```

table two

```
id  | category 
i_1 | c_345
```

Here is my current code (which returns no rows):

```
select a.id, a.category
from one a 
left join two b 
on a.id=b.id 
where a.category != b.category;
```

The ideal result should look like this:

```
id  | category
i_1 | c_123
i_1 | c_234
i_1 | c_456
i_2 | c_456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for instead:

```
select a.id, a.category
from one a 
  left join two b 
    on a.id=b.id 
      and a.category = b.category
where b.id is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8bf4/4)

This returns all records from table one that don't exist in table two matching on the id and category.  Your query is negating the `outer join`.  I'm not sure if `hive` supports `not exists`, but that may even be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This solution only works for [Hive 0.13+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-784).

[Here's](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) the manual reference for `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
select a.id, a.category
from one a 
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from two b 
  where a.id = b.id and a.category = b.category
)
```

It's worth mentioning that it **can** perform faster than `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE x IS NULL` on some DBMS.

I consider it a better practice, because you don't need to read entire query to notice that the `LEFT JOIN` is in fact an anti join.

Comment: the solution still NOT EXISTS does not work, returns the same result as code I posted in my question

Comment: @jKraut "the same result" would be? You've said in your question, that your approach results in no rows. Is there any error, or simply no rows are returned?